# how to fetch data correctly with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have problem with fetch data from database (firestore)

im fetching data from firestore and listing them with listview.builder, when a card is tapped it routes to new page that show all the details of tapped item.

on the screenshot i have 2 item listed with header,body and date when i tapped on item routes to new page and fetch from firestore rest of the data (client,start date,finish date etc.)

my question is what is the best way to fetch tapped items datas

my idea is store somehow items store unique id to the builded item and when it tapped route to new page with id and query with id

my code block

```
Widget listener(Stream<QuerySnapshot> tasks) {
  return Expanded(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: tasks,
    builder: (
      BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
    ) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            "something went wrong.",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: ColorConstants.instance.headerColor, fontSize: 20),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.data!.size > 0) {
        final data = snapshot.requireData;
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.size,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildNotificationCards(
                context,
                data.docs[index]['header'],
                data.docs[index]['body'],
                data.docs[index]['startDate']));
      } else {
        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    LineIcons.fileAlt,
                    size: 60,
                    color: ColorConstants.instance.headerColor,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Maalesef Kayıtlı Bir Veri Bulunamadı',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConstants.instance.headerColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        height: 2),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste your actual code here so we can test in our IDE. BTW, in Dart, instead of checking `if (xxx.size > 0)` there is a helper method: `if (xxx.isNotEmpty)`. There is also `.isEmpty`.

Comment: i know isnotempty and isempty but these are not working i don't know why they returns just empty screen, not no data screen that i designed

Answer (score 0):

The normal practice is under `ListView.builder`, you create a `ListTile` and on its `onTap` argument, you use the Navigator to switch to another page for the detail view:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(data[index])),
);
```

where `data[index]` is the particular element of the `data` list you want to display the contents of.